# Как можно выделить белые свечения на ультрафиолетовом изображении?Python

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

Вот изображение в ультрафиолете,нужно найти и выделить эти белые свечения ,через какой метод это можно реализовать на Python?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте изображение

Comment: Добавил изображение

Comment: объясните, как и что именно вам нужно "Выделить". Невооруженным глазом видно, что белого на вашем изображении нет. Есть зоны большей и меньшей яркости. Вам яркие зоны нужно "выделить"? Далее, как именно выделить - построить массив двумерных координат ярких точек, построить контуры вокруг областей повышенной яркости, сделать что-то ещё?

Comment: Нужно найти в каком интервале эти белые свечения

Comment: Где тут белое ?